# Added contact doesn't sync with google account

Tags: java, android, contacts

I have an app where i am trying to add an account to google contacts, but when i add the contact that appear to be phone contact rather than going to google account. I have set the account type to google and account name while adding the contact, but still it doesn't sync and appear to be phone contact.

Following is the code

```
public void createContact(Contact contact,String account) {


    String DisplayName = contact.getFirstName() +" "+contact.getLastName();
    String MobileNumber = contact.getMobile();
    String HomeNumber = contact.getHome();
    String WorkNumber = contact.getWork();
    String emailID = contact.getEmail();
    String company = contact.getCompany();
    String jobTitle = "";


    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "Google")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
            .build());

    //------------------------------------------------------ Names
    if (DisplayName != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        DisplayName).build());
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number
    if (MobileNumber != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
                newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, MobileNumber)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .build());
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------ Home Numbers
    if (HomeNumber != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, HomeNumber)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                .build());
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------ Work Numbers
    if (WorkNumber != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, WorkNumber)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------ Email
    if (emailID != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailID)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------ Organization
   // if (!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals("")) {
    if(company != null && jobTitle != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, company)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, jobTitle)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());
    }

    // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact
    try {
        getActivity().getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Not able to figure out whats wrong with above could.

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the issue after reading android docs for nearly two hours change thats required is as follows

```
    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google")
```

Hope this helps someone.